# Update TextField StyleSheet doesn't make any effect

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ide, stylesheet

I'm trying to update some TextField's style, eg. color, fontSize, fontFamily.
I'm creating field by:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();

var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
style.parseCSS("p{color: #000000; fontFamily: System; fontSize: 20px;}");

        textField.styleSheet = style;

        textField.selectable = false;
        //textField.embedFonts = true;
        textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;           

        ///textField.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        textField.text = text;
        textField.wordWrap = true;

        textField.width = 800;
        textField.height = 40;

        some_other_mc.addChild(textField);
```

Then I'm trying to **update** textField:

```
   private function SetStyle(name:String, value:String):void {

        var current_styles:Object = _active_text_field.styleSheet.getStyle('p');

        switch(name) {

            case 'color':
                current_styles.color = value;
            break;

            case 'fontSize':
                current_styles.fontSize = value;
            break;

            case 'fontFamily':
                current_styles.fontFamily = value;
            break;

        }

         _active_text_field.styleSheet.setStyle('p', current_styles);

    }
```

The **_active_text_field** is linked to **textField**.

Every trigger SetStyle makes no changes. I can't find bug for a long time.

Please and thank you for any help :)

Comment: Are you seeing the style that you set first for the text field?

Comment: I tried your code and your SetStyle function and is working just as expected... are you sure your text inside your String "text" variable has HTML <p> and </p> (paragraph) tags?

Comment: I used "current_styles.color = '#'+value;" and color's changing, but still I can't change font size

Comment: check this, it's working fine for me: http://wonderfl.net/c/f3iX

Comment: @danii even in Your script font size doesn't changing, only font :/

Comment: check it yourself, copy the code (or fork the project) and just change the line setStyle("fontSize","50"); to whatever value and you'll see how the green letters change size... are you sure your _active_text_field is the textfield you are working with and not something else?

Comment: I did it, all is good now. Thx all for help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take this simple sample

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.StyleSheet;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

public class StyleSheetExample extends Sprite {

    public function StyleSheetExample() {
        var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

        var heading:Object = new Object();
        heading.fontWeight = "bold";
        heading.color = "#FF0000";

        var body:Object = new Object();
        body.fontStyle = "italic";

        style.setStyle(".heading", heading);
        style.setStyle("body", body);

        var label:TextField = new TextField();
        label.styleSheet = style;
        label.htmlText = "<body><span class='heading'>Hello </span>World...</body>";
        addChild(label);
    }
  }
}
```